# Is it possible to find a vector that is orthogonal to this set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

I have a set of four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$:  $\{ \vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3, \vec v_4 \}$ The first three are linearly independent, but $ \vec v_4 $ is a linear combination of the others. Is it possible to find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is orthogonal to $\{ \vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3, \vec v_4 \}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Find a vector orthogonal to $\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3$ (by Gram-Schmidt). It is automatically also orthogonal to $\vec v_4$.